# Suggest improvements to my database schema

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I'm making a system to record when someone's vehicle is blocked by another in the car park. Notifications are sent to the relevant people and a web front-end allows them to add/remove vehicles. The user can also manage their own vehicle information and record basic information about them, add/remove, etc. I'm a little stuck on the database side though....

Queries will need to be done to find / update  information about a person's vehicle (`select * from vehicles where peopleID = @peopleID` or `insert into vehicles...`), show who you are "blocking" (`select * from blocked where blockedby = @peopleID`), etc. These are obviously simplified and I will create stored procedures once I'm happy with the schema. Just wanted to show example usage.

Schema is as below, so far:

`Blocked` table:

```
+----+-----------+----------+-----------+-------------------------+---------------+
| id | vehicleID | peopleID | blockedBy |        dateTime         |   comments    |
+----+-----------+----------+-----------+-------------------------+---------------+
|  1 |         1 |        1 |         1 | 2016-11-24 09:00:00.000 | test comments |
|  2 |         2 |        2 |         1 | 2016-12-07 15:00:00.000 | test          |
+----+-----------+----------+-----------+-------------------------+---------------+
```

`People` table:

```
+----------+----------+
| peopleID |   name   |
+----------+----------+
|        1 | Person 1 |
|        2 | Person 2 |
+----------+----------+
```

`Vehicles` table:

```
+-----------+----------+----------------+--------+--------+
| vehicleID | peopleID |   makeModel    | regNo  | colour |
+-----------+----------+----------------+--------+--------+
|         1 |        1 | Bugatti Veyron |  12345 | White  |
|         2 |        2 | Porsche 911    |  67891 | Black  |
+-----------+----------+----------------+--------+--------+
```

Am I approaching this in the right way? I'm not sure if I'm over complicating things. I could probably get away with two tables but information would likely be repeated. Any advice appreciated.

Comment: For normalized data you should not have peopleId on the Blocked table as it is already on the Vehicle table, and you will have a foreign key between the Blocked and Vehicle tables. Also was is blockedBy? A person or a vehicle, I would make that column slightly more descriptive.

Comment: Do you really need people table? Unless one person can have 2 cars (which would mean different table setup), you can just merge vehicles and people into one table. You can do it with just 2 tables: Car/Person and Blocked.

Comment: kyle - blocked by is the person who parked in front of someone else. if that makes sense. I will look at removing the duplicate personID. @yosh - Each person can have as many cars as they desire but the max would generally be 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest version could be:

```
Vehicles
+-----------+---------+----------------+--------+--------+
| vehicleID | owner   |   makeModel    | regNo  | colour |
+-----------+---------+----------------+--------+--------+
|         1 | John    | Bugatti Veyron |  12345 | White  |
|         2 | Bob     | Porsche 911    |  67891 | Black  |
+-----------+---------+----------------+--------+--------+
```

vehicleID can be unique primary key.

```
Blocked
+----+-----------+-------------+--------------+----------+
| id | vehicleID | blockedByID |   dateTime   | comments |
+----+-----------+-------------+--------------+----------+
|  1 |         1 |           3 |              |          |
|  2 |         3 |           5 |              |          |
+----+-----------+-------------+--------------+----------+
```

The first column is just a unique row ID that could even be auto incremented.

Comment: In the 2nd table, is `blockedByID` a FK reference to `vehicleID`?

Comment: @JayF1 Yes, it's a FK. Not sure about other databases, but in MSSQL you could easily create a "cascade delete" constraint that would automatically delete all records (unblock cars blocked by this one) with this FK if you delete vehicle (car drives away) from table.

Comment: That could work, although the system will email each 'blocked in' person as the row is deleted. I'll see if I can figure out how to do this en mass. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please see my suggestion below

1 ) add primary key for each table, and if possible foreign key as well

2 ) Vehicle table - instead of calling peopleId, call it ownerId, because this is a vehicle table and owner is just a property of vehicle. Though it will refer to peopleId only.

3) Blocked table - Blocked by is not needed, because people are not blocking but slot is blocked by vehicle. If needed owner name can be fetched from vehicle database through query

4) Blcoked Table-It missing parking slot number

5) Parking Slot Table - need this table, it will have slot id, allowed vehicle id ( 1 to many ) and owner id.

Comment: Thanks, ownerId makes more sense. There is no requirement for parking 'slots'. I have a PK on each table already. Point 2 and 3 are helpful though